# String to DateTime BigQuery

Tags: sql, string, datetime, google-bigquery

I have a column with strings as datetimes. I want to convert the whole column to datetime format.

```
Example
"19.03.2020 08:14:13"
"30.04.2020 08:57:45"
```

I tried this:

```
select *,
PARSE_DATETIME("%d%m%y %H:%M:%S", Example) as Date_example
from xx.yy.zz
```

but i got an error
**Failed to parse input string "19.03.2020 08:14:13"**

Can anyone help me and tell me why this is not working? Is it because day,month and year are separated by the dot instead of slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```sql
PARSE_DATETIME('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S', example) as Date_example
```

Rationale:

- your original format specifier is missing the dot separator between the date components
- you want `%Y` rather than `%y` for the year component (the former is a 4 digits year, while the later is 2 digits)

We can shorten the query a little with `%T`:

```sql
PARSE_DATETIME('%d.%m.%Y %T', example) as Date_example
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you maybe know why i am getting 2020-07-05T07:18:48 this T in between date and time..